# MacMini is unable to communicate with devices on netwrok

Tags: network, wifi, mac-mini, printing

Devices:

- Router: 192.168.0.1
- MacMini 192.168.0.97
- MacBook 192.168.0.19
- Printer 192.168.0.99
- Windows 192.168.0.49

So, my problem is that a strange one.

All my devices are connected to the same router.

Here are the Ping Results.

- Router - MacMini: Response
- Router - MacBook: Response
- Router - Printer: Response
- Router - Windows: No Response
- MacMini - Router: Response
- MacMini - Windows: No response
- MacMini - Printer: No Response
- ManMini - MacBook: Response
- Windows - Router: Response
- Windows - MacMini: No Response
- Windows - MacBook: Response
- Windows - Printer: No Response
- MacBook - Router: Response
- MacBook - Printer: Response
- MacBook - MacMini: Response
- MacBook - Windows: No Response.

Basically, my ping results are all over the place. Some devices can connect to others, but no vise versa.

All devices can ping the router, but the Router cannot ping all devices.

I have no idea what is going on here, and I'm not even sure where to begin.

I hope I've provided enough information, please let me know if I need to give more.

Comment: Have you power cycled all the devices and disabled all firewalls and then tested?

Comment: Yes I have. This all started because the MacMini lost connectivity to the Printer. Now I've discovered so many communication breaks in my network. (Everything can access the web online)

Comment: Can you give us the model and make of your router?

Comment: It's an asus ac68u running shibby tomato